# How can we access visualforce page for pdf generation from a future annotated method

Tags: apex, visualforce, future, getcontentaspdf

I have a future annotated method which should generate a pdf in PdfController, the method is as below:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void savePdfAsAttachment(Id applicationId){
    PageReference p = Page.PdfGeneratorPage;
    p.getParameters().put('applicationId', applicationId);
    Blob pdfBlob;
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
        pdfBlob = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
    } else {
        pdfBlob = p.getContent();
    }
    Application__c applicationRecord = [Select id, Name from Application__c where id = :applicationId];
    
    Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
    attachmentPDF.parentId = applicationId;
    attachmentPDF.Name = applicationRecord.Name;
    attachmentPDF.contentType = 'application/pdf';
    attachmentPDF.Description = '';
    attachmentPDF.Body = pdfBlob;
    List<Attachment> attachments = [select id from Attachment where parentId =:applicationId and name =: attachmentPDF.Name];
    if(!attachments.isEmpty()){
        attachmentPDF.Id = attachments[0].Id;
    }
    upsert attachmentPDF;
}
```

when this method is called from a method from AppController (most of main business logic is inside this one), like below:

```
@Auraenabled
public static void updateApplication(Id applicationRecordId) {
    ...... // code for other business logic is here
    update objApp;
    PdfController.savePdfAsAttachment(applicationRecordId);
}
```

I am getting below error once it executes PdfController.savePdfAsAttachment method

> You do not have sufficient privileges to access the page:
> /apex/pdfgeneratorpage

[image]

Can anybody help me resolve this issue please.

Comment: Does the running user's profile have access to the page?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, grant the permission on either the Profile or Permission Set for the user to page 'pdfgeneratorpage' as Aditya mentioned.